# Creating a list of items with multiplicities in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have an issue with the creation of lists.

I have a function that returns the roots of a polynomial (see below). What I obtain is a list of roots (`R.keys()`) and the times each one appears in the solution (`R.values()`).

When I obtain `R.items()` I am given a set of pairs of roots and their multiplicities: `[(-2, 2), (-1, 1), (-3, 3)]` as returned from the example below.

But what I want is to obtain a list with each root repeated by the number of times it appears, that is, `[-2, -2, -1, -3, -3, -3]`.

I guess this is not difficult but I'm getting stuck with finding a solution.

```
pol=Lambda((y), y**6 + 14*y**5 + 80*y**4 + 238*y**3 + 387*y**2 + 324*y + 108)
poli=Poly(pol(y))
R=roots(poli)
R.keys()
R.values()
R.items()

def list_of_roots(poli):
    return(R.items())
list_of_roots(poli)
```

Comment: Did you mean `[-2, -2, -1, -3, -3, -3]`?

Comment: What type is `R`? I.e., what is `type(R)`? And are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Yes, `[-2, -2, -1, -3, -3, -3]`, I've corrected it, thanks for this. I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_list_of_roots(poli):
    # initialize an empty list 
    list_of_roots = []
    # process your poli object to get roots
    R = roots(poli)
    # we obtain the key value pairs using R.items()
    for root, multiplicity in R.items():
        # extend the list_of_roots with each root by multiplicity amount
        list_of_roots += [root] * multiplicity
    return list_of_roots
```

EDIT: Processed poli within function since you seem to want to pass poli to it.

EDIT: Added explanation of code.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the list of items in the form of an `Array<Tuple>`, then you can create a `list` like this:

```
items = [(-2, 2), (-1, 1), (-3, 3)]
listOfRoots = []
for x in items:
    for y in range(x[1]):
        listOfRoots.append(x[0])
print(listOfRoots)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
roots = [(-2, 2), (-1, 1), (-3, 3)]
[ r for (root, mult) in roots for r in [root] * mult]

[-2, -2, -1, -3, -3, -3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [(-2, 2), (-1, 1), (-3, 3)]
result = []
for val, mult in items:
  result.extend(mult * [val])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean [-2, -2, -1, -3, -3, -3].

```
roots1 = [(-2, 2), (-1, 1), (-3, 3)]
roots2 = [i for (r, m) in roots1 for i in [r] * m]
```

This might be of interest: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)